# PowerBI_variables_error message "cannot convert value of type Text to type TRUE/FALSE"

Tags: variables, powerbi

In PowerBI I have a table like this:

[image]

I created a measure to calculate the total head count for selected groups and selected age:

```
head count_total = 
VAR
  Category = FILTER(ALL('table'[group]), 'table'[group] = "apple" || "pear")
VAR
  includeage = FILTER(ALL('table'[age]), table[age]>=20)
RETURN
  CALCULATE(SUM('table'[head count]), Category, includeage)
```

I get this error message:

> Cannot convert value “pear” of type Text to type TRUE/FALSE

Can anyone help diagnose where went wrong in the coding? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `'table'[group] = "apple" || "pear"` is not correct. It compares table value with "apple", and the boolean result from this operation is "or"-ed with "pear". In this context "pear" should be a boolean value, while it is a text. Thus the error message. The correct expression in this case is `'table'[group] = "apple" || 'table'[group] = "pear"` or `'table'[group] in { "apple" , "pear" }`, so the measure should be (adding quotes around one table reference):

```
head count_total = 
VAR
  Category = FILTER(ALL('table'[group]), 'table'[group] = "apple" || 'table'[group] = "pear")
VAR
  includeage = FILTER(ALL('table'[age]), 'table'[age]>=20)
RETURN
  CALCULATE(SUM('table'[head count]), Category, includeage)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrey! I have make corrections to my coding, it works out well! Cheers.

Comment: Hi Andrey, may I ask another question for this table? can the return function return two different results based on different criteria? e.g. if group is "apple" or "pear", return the sum of head counts; if the group is orange or watermelon, return twice the sum of head counts? (both grouping require age>20). Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, you can. If `Category2` is the same, but for orange/watermelon, then the return can be `CALCULATE(SUM('table'[head count]); Category; includeage) + 2 * CALCULATE(SUM('table'[head count]); Category2; includeage)`

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey. that helps a lot!