POWER BI - OR Operator Error "Cannot convert value "FOULS COMMITTED" of type Text to type True/False"
How can I adjust my code to get correct ?
MyRank =
VAR ThisGroup = Rankings[Attribute]
RETURN
IF(Rankings[Attribute] = "GOALS CONCEDED" || "FOULS COMITTED" || "OWN HALF BALL LOSS" || "YELLOW CARDS" || "RED CARDS",
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            Rankings,
            Rankings[Attribute] = ThisGroup
        ),
        Rankings[Value],
        , ASC
        ,
        Dense
    ))
 

Theres an error: "Cannot convert value "FOULS COMMITTED" of type Text to type True/False"

This question is similar to: What is wrong with this Switch statement? Im getting error cannot convert value text to type True/False and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274739/powerbi-variables-error-message-cannot-convert-value-of-type-text-to-type-true . If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In DAX, you can't use the || operator between string values without repeating the comparison for each value.  Try this instead:
MyRank =
VAR ThisGroup = Rankings[Attribute]
RETURN
IF(
    Rankings[Attribute] = "GOALS CONCEDED" ||
    Rankings[Attribute] = "FOULS COMMITTED" ||
    Rankings[Attribute] = "OWN HALF BALL LOSS" ||
    Rankings[Attribute] = "YELLOW CARDS" ||
    Rankings[Attribute] = "RED CARDS",
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            Rankings,
            Rankings[Attribute] = ThisGroup
        ),
        Rankings[Value],
        , ASC,
        DENSE
    )
)


The OR operator (||) in your case is expecting two Boolean values, but you are providing text values, simply you can use IN {...,...}
MyRank =
VAR ThisGroup = Rankings[Attribute]
RETURN
IF(
    Rankings[Attribute] IN { "GOALS CONCEDED", "FOULS COMMITTED", "OWN HALF BALL LOSS", "YELLOW CARDS", "RED CARDS" },
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            Rankings,
            Rankings[Attribute] = ThisGroup
        ),
        Rankings[Value],
        , ASC,
        Dense
    )
)

Please keep in mind that I provided the correction to what you provided and you may need to pay attention to performance issues.
